# NSURLErrorDomain -1001 The request timed out on device

Tags: ios, https, connection-timeout

Ive been seeing this error on a production app I have on and off for about a year now on iOS versions 9, 10 and 11 from both iPad and iPhone devices.

In my app, if I get an error, I send it to my website and (assuming it can connect), I see the error in my apache logs.

In the past few days Ive been seeing one particular person running an iPhone device which continually gets this error (parsed from actual error):

```
NSURLErrorDomain -1001 The request timed out.
```

Since my app retries the server, Im seeing this over and over
every 15 seconds in my logs, so obviously the same HTTPS code I use to
connect to the server is also sending me the error log message.

Ive tried searching around but have found no explanation on what is really
causing this or what I can do to "fix" the issue on my production app.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!